# Hilbert Spaces; eigenvalues of $PBP$ vs. $B$ for $B$ compact selfadjoint and $P$ orthoprojection.

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

An exercise I have come upon while studying Hilbert Spaces:

Let $A$ be a compact operator, and $P \in L(H)$ be an orthoprojection. Prove that $$\lambda_n (PA^*AP) \leq \lambda_n (A^*A)$$ 
(Where $\lambda$'s are the eigenvalues, and the indexing is from the minimax principle, i.e. $\lambda_1$ is the biggest eigenvalue, and so on.)

There's also a hint:

Define $B = A^*A$, then $B$ is compact self-adjoint. Then
$$Bx = \sum_n \lambda_n \langle x,\phi_n \rangle \phi_n$$
$$PBPx = \sum_n \lambda_n \langle x,P\phi_n \rangle P\phi_n$$
"...and from there the proof is trivial."

But I do not see the triviality of how to continue. The biggest problem for me, conceptually, is that I can not manage to separate the corresponding eigenvalues to compare between the two, they always come all together in a sum.

I do not ask for the complete proof with all the details, but perhaps someone could outline the idea of the proof in general? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the [min-max theorem for compact operators,](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Compact_operators)
$$\lambda_n(B)=\mbox{max }_{\mbox{dim }V=n}\mbox{min }_{x\in V,\|x\|=1}\langle Bx,x\rangle.$$
If $\lambda_n(PBP)=0$, there is nothing to prove, so assume $\lambda_n(PBP)>0$. Pick an $n$-dimensional subspace $V$ such that
$$\lambda_n(PBP)=\mbox{min }_{x\in V,\|x\|=1}\langle BPx,Px\rangle.$$
Now, since $\lambda_n(PBP)>0$, we have $\|Px\|>0$ for all $x\in V$, and thus
\begin{align*}
\mbox{min }_{x\in V,\|x\|=1}\langle BPx,Px\rangle&= \mbox{min }_{x\in V,\|x\|=1}\|Px\|^2\langle BPx/ \|Px\|,Px/\|Px\|\rangle\\
& \leq \mbox{min }_{x\in PV,\|x\|=1}\langle Bx,x\rangle.
\end{align*}
Again, since $\|Px\|>0$, it follows that $\dim PV=\dim V$, and therefore
$$\lambda_n(PBP)=\mbox{min }_{x\in V,\|x\|=1}\langle Bx,x\rangle\leq \mbox{max }_{\mbox{dim }V=n}\mbox{min }_{x\in V,\|x\|=1}\langle Bx,x\rangle=\lambda_n(B).$$

Comment: Not really. First of all, what you have shown, is that $PBP \leq B$, correct? Or am I missing something?

Anyway, from that I can get the inequality for $\lambda_1$. By plugging in $\tilde x_1$, the first unit eigenvector of $PBP$ into the inequality. Then $LHS = \tilde \lambda_1$ and $RHS \leq \lambda_1 ||\tilde x_1|| = \lambda_1$ (From maximality of $\lambda_1$).

But this does not work for the rest of the eigenvectors.

Comment: Indeed that is what I have shown. Check out the [min-max principle for compact operators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Min-max_theorem#Compact_operators). Basically, it allows you to do what you have done for the largest eigenvalues with the smaller eigenvalues as well.

Comment: Wait... is it really that simple? One line?
$\tilde \lambda_{n+1} = \min_{x_1,...x_n} \sup_{x \in \{x_1,...x_n\}^{\perp}} \frac {\langle PBPx,x \rangle}{||x||} \leq \min_{x_1,...x_n} \sup_{x \in \{x_1,...x_n\}^{\perp}} \frac {\langle Bx,x \rangle}{||x||} = \lambda_{n+1}$

Comment: Indeed. The 'tough' part is that you need to know stuff about compact operators.

Comment: We only use compactness to justify the use of $\leq$ for operators (and the minimax principle), right?

Comment: We use compactness essentially when we state that $B$ has an orthonormal eigenbasis (and this is of course the main step in showing $PBP\leq B$, although I get the feeling that this property holds true in general for a positive bounded operator). Furthermore, the min-max principle becomes more involved if you want to apply it to a general bounded (or unbounded) operator.

Comment: Actually, I may have found fault with your proof. Let's tahe $H = R^2$. $B$ is a projection onto $span\{(1,0)\}$ (compact due to finite dimension), and $P$ be a projection onto $span\{(1,1)\}$. Then $\forall x \in span\{(0,1)\}$ $\langle Bx,x \rangle = 0$, but $\langle PBPx, x \rangle$ is not necessarily 0.

Comment: Of course you are completely right! I have edited my answer, which now relies only on the min-max principle. It is completely unclear to me how the hint is of any use.